# How to install Python 3 if I want to use Python 2 with Django on Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, python-3.x

I have program that requires Python 3, but I develop Django and it uses Python 2.
What to do, to use both of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install both. Python 3 uses a different executable name so the two won't conflict and the [Debian python policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-python.html#s-versions) (adopted by Ubuntu) states that the two major versions are to be kept as separate architectures.

Python versions are installed with the major and minor version number (python2.7, python3.2), but Ubuntu will create `python` and `python3` aliases for your python 2 and python 3 installations (linked to `python2.7` and `python3.2` respectively).

Your Django development will continue to use `python` and your Python 3 program will use `python3`.